# Run code when $refs.theReference has been set

Tags: vue.js

I'm showing/hiding a canvas dynamically, and when it's about to be shown, I want to draw on it. I use a `data` variable (`true`/`false`) to insert/remove the canvas, and I `watch` it to draw on it when this value changes. I've added a `ref=canvas` on the canvas to get a reference to the canvas DOM element, but when my `watch` callback is called,  `this.$refs.canvas` hasn't been assigned any value yet.

Here is an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/3v9Lbjbr/3/

Any good way to solve this other than to defer the drawing operations with `setTimeout`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `$nextTick` method provided by Vuejs.
You can read more about it in the docs: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Async-Update-Queue

Here is an example for your use case:

```js
var demo = new Vue({
    el: '#demo',
    data: {
        showCanvas: false,
    },
    methods: {
        show: function(){
        this.showCanvas = true
      }
    },
    watch: {
      'showCanvas': function() {
        this.$nextTick(function() {
          alert(this.$refs.canvas);
        }.bind(this))
      }
    }
})
```

```css
canvas{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="demo" v-cloak>
   <p v-on:click="show">
   Show canvas.
   </p>
   <canvas v-if="showCanvas" ref="canvas"></canvas>
</div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
```